# Delete specific spaces from a string Python

Tags: python, string

How should I delete a spaces in string   `_ y _  _ o _` so that spaces only from around letters be deleted but not the ones between "_" symbols?

Comment: Please show the actual function.

Comment: So where is your attempt, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: def hangman(word, letters):
    x = ''
    for letter in word:
        if letter in letters:
            x += letter
            
        else:
            x += ' _ '
    
    return x
                  
print hangman('python', ['a', 'r', 'y', 'i', 'o'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through re.sub.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Za-z])\s+|\s+(?=[A-Za-z])', '', '_ y _ _ o _')
'_y_ _o_'
```

`(?<=[A-Za-z])\s+` matches one or more space characters only if it's proceeded by a letter. `|` or it would  match `\s+(?=[A-Za-z])` match one or more spaces which was followed by a letter.

**OR**

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s*([A-Za-z]+)\s*', r'\1', '_ y _ _ o _')
'_y_ _o_'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
def hangman(word, letters):
    replace = r'[%s]' % ''.join(letters)
    return re.sub(replace, '_', word)
```